# When should foreign keys be used?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When should foreign keys be used?

It was explained to me that foreign keys should be used any time repeated data comes up and we just save IDs to save space.  The database I'm making has a few thousand records, with categories and counties (probably a few dozen uniques in each column).  So I can make separate tables for counties and categories with name and a primary key id.  And it would make the database about 5% smaller.

But is that the only benefit?

It's making everything else more complex--adding IDs for counties and categories which wouldn't otherwise be needed.  When looking at the table in phpLiteAdmin, it just shows you a number instead of the category/county name, making it more difficult to visualize.

What are the advantages of using foreign keys and making separate tables in this situation?

Or should I just not do that and stick with all the data (repetition and all) in one table?

Would it make sense to make the counties/categories tables just one column with no numeric primary key, since they'll all be uniques anyway?

That would at least show the full names in phpLiteAdmin.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/db

Comment: What you are really asking is "What is a 'normalized database?' and 'what are the benefits (and trade offs) of working with normalized data?'

Comment: [Foreign Keys - What do they do for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434951/3404097) etc etc

Answer (score 3):

If you are using foreign key. its also called as referential integrity.

Suppose you have two table first table is account_user and second is account_user_detail.

so account_user table will have primary key of account_number of account_id. and account_user_detail table will have accounts holder address detail.

so if you are relating both the tables then account_number or account_id will be same.

so using value of primary key in second table we define foreign key.

foreign key identifies that value of account_number in second table is reference of Mr. Xyz in first table with same account number.

So Foreign key is used for joining two table with a column that is common to both tables and share same unique value.

Comment: @Nimal Kumar: Referential Integrity refers to a guarantee that many RDBMs make about the consistency of your foreign keys during database updates.  It is not correct to say that "foreign keys are also called referential integrity" because it is not necessary to enforce referemtial integrity when using them.  Versions of SQLite, for example, before 3.6 did not offer referential integrity as a database feature (referential integrity must be enabled to be used with current versions).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow... it sounds like you're just explaining what foreign keys are.  I understand foreign keys just fine and use them pretty regularly.  My question is asking when it makes sense to use them if the parent table would have just one column of data.  And if it would make sense to use that one column of unique data as the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [this](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> SQL foreign key constraints are used to enforce "exists" relationships
>   between tables.

**EDIT:-**

The foreign key constraints exist is to guarantee that the referenced rows exist.

Also the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) says:-

> One important part of database design is making sure that
>   relationships between real-world entities are reflected in the
>   database by references, using foreign keys to refer from one table to
>   another.[9] Another important part of database design is database
>   normalization, in which tables are broken apart and foreign keys make
>   it possible for them to be reconstructed.

Also check this Thread.

[Why are foreign keys more used in theory than in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876013/why-are-foreign-keys-more-used-in-theory-than-in-practice)

Comment: So is that their only advantage?  To make sure that county/category exists if a new row is being inserted?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed:- This may also help you when you want to delete some row from the table. Besides there are many advantages of using foreign key in your table. **NOTE:-** In SQLITE the foreign key is by default are disabled

Comment: @DanGoodspeed:- I would also suggest you to understand the concept of normalisation as that would definietly help you!! :)

Comment: I do turn on foreign keys every time I open a connection to the database, but thanks for the heads up about that.  I believe I understand the concept of normalization pretty well, I'm just asking about the benefits of having a one-column parent table.  So far I haven't heard anything more than that it restricts what can be written to that column.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed:- foreign key constraints exist is to guarantee that the referenced rows exist.

Comment: I guess, though it's not that difficult for me (maybe one line of code) to check to make sure that the county/category exists in the database if it's all in one table.  I haven't heard any input on making the parent tables (the county and category tables) just one column using their unique names as the primary key instead of integers.  What are the pros/cons of that?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed:- Although there are many pros of using foreign key but I found this one most important:- **When Optimizer knows about the relationships between tables in the database then it plan your queries for most efficient execution.**

Comment: @DanGoodspeed:- And one cons can be that:- **You are making the DB work extra on every CRUD operation because it has to check FK consistency.**

Comment: I'm not sure if that really answered the question about using the unique content as the primary key instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If your country name is "United States of America" this is 24bytes. If you use a foriegn key you will need only 2-4 bytes. Thats a huge difference.

When you are searching for a country name it is going to be very fast because you only have to match a number and not the whole string.

Also if you use an index on the country_id field it is going to much smaller.

I can understand you point about the added complexity. In your case you can get away with not using foreign keys but you shouldn't. You will eventually need them so better be prepared and experienced on the subject.

Comment: I guess my thoughts are this - All of the categories and counties are just one word, usually about 10 characters or so.  And average row of data is probably about 250 characters.  So going from 250 bytes to 242 bytes really isn't that huge of a difference.  I'm also not 100% sold on the speed.  In your case, it would have to look up the country id for the US, then go to the main table and look for rows with that ID.  Seems like an extra step for the computer if the country ID isn't known prior to the search.

Comment: Yes it is an extra step. But matching 1000 strings is way slower than matching 1000 numbers

Answer (score 0):

> But is that the only benefit?

No.

Foreign keys are logically similar to pointers or references in most programming languages. Imagine trying to make some data structure by just copying data, without being able to reference anything. A database without foreign keys would be similarly problematic.

Without the ability to reference things, you'd have to make sure all the copies are kept up-to date. If there is a bug that leads to one copy being updated but not the other, that would effectively **corrupt** the data - you'd no longer know which copy is correct.

Avoiding redundancies is not primarily about space, it's about data integrity. The whole purpose of database normalization (which couldn't be done without foreign keys) is the avoidance of redundancies and therefore the protection the data integrity.

---

In your particular case...

- Should a category (or country) be able to exist without being connected to any row from the main table?
- Is there any data that should exist for a category, independently from which rows in the main table this category is connected to?
- Is there any operation (like rename) that should be done independently?

If either answer is "yes", you should put categories into a separate lookup table. Whether this lookup table should use natural (name) or surrogate (ID) key is a different issue. Some pros and cons are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info).

Comment: I understand foreign keys just fine, it's their necessity when referencing a one-column table that I'm trying to get.  The answers to your three questions are no, no, and maybe.  The suggestion that my client may want to rename a category does exist.  And it would be easier to just change the name once in a category table, then to go through the main table and change it each time.  Though it would be a really rare occurrence.  Even more rare that a county decides to change its name.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed You wrote: _"I'm just starting to learn SQL (using SQLite) and I'm trying to figure out when foreign keys should be used."_. You should have worded that differently if you didn't want general introductory answers that you eventually got from us. To your concrete question: according to your answers, it is possible you don't need a separate lookup table (and the accompanying FK). It all depends on what kind of requirements you need to represent, and you know your requirements better than we do...

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key constraints are used to **restrict the values that are allowed to exist** in a column or set of columns. For example, take marriages:

```
CREATE TABLE person
        (person_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name varchar NOT NULL
        );

CREATE TABLE marriage
        ( person1 INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , person2 INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , comment varchar
        , CONSTRAINT marriage_1 FOREIGN KEY (person1) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        , CONSTRAINT marriage_2 FOREIGN KEY (person2) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        , CONSTRAINT order_in_court CHECK (person1 < person2)
        );

-- add some data ...
INSERT INTO person(person_id,name) values (1,'Bob'),(2,'Alice'),(3,'Charles');

INSERT INTO marriage(person1,person2, comment) VALUES(1,2, 'Crypto marriage!') ; -- Ok
INSERT INTO marriage(person1,person2, comment) VALUES(2,1, 'Not twice!' ) ; -- Should fail
INSERT INTO marriage(person1,person2, comment) VALUES(3,3, 'No you dont...' ) ; -- Should fail
INSERT INTO marriage(person1,person2, comment) VALUES(2,3, 'OMG she did it again.' ) ; -- Should fail (does not)
INSERT INTO marriage(person1,person2, comment) VALUES(3,4, 'Non existant persons are not allowed to marry !' ) ; -- Should fail

SELECT p1.name, p2.name, m.comment
FROM marriage m
JOIN person p1 ON m.person1 = p1.person_id
JOIN person p2 ON m.person2 = p2.person_id
        ;
```

The above DDL tries to model marriages (and partly fails) The constraints to be modelled are:

- only **existing** persons can be married
- marriages can only exist between two **different** persons
- A person can only be married **once**

The output:

```
INSERT 0 3
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  new row for relation "marriage" violates check constraint "order_in_court"
ERROR:  new row for relation "marriage" violates check constraint "order_in_court"
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  insert or update on table "marriage" violates foreign key constraint "marriage_2"
DETAIL:  Key (person2)=(4) is not present in table "person".
 name  |  name   |        comment        
-------+---------+-----------------------
 Bob   | Alice   | Crypto marriage!
 Alice | Charles | OMG she did it again.
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I understand foreign keys just fine, it's their necessity when referencing a unique one-column table (like "category") that I'm trying to get. So far, I've been told it would save a little space, it makes it harder to insert a non-category into the column, and it's easier to re-name.  All pretty minor reasons.

Comment: It is not about _space_, it is not about _speed_. It is about _correctness_. FK constrains are part of the data model. And the data model only represents a (restricted) view of the world outside. (such as: you can only marry an existing person, which makes perfect sense: in the real world you cannot marrry a non-existing person either)