# Can someone explain what a Foreign Key is, and why you use it?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm in the middle of learning C# and i'm going towards learning about SQL databases, but i'm not sure i quite understand the Foreign-Key?

Thank you beforehand

Comment: There are many tutorials on other site about databases, sql and foreign-keys as well. Search for any available. Stackoverflow is not the right place to search, if you're looking for a tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Keys - What do they do for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434951/foreign-keys-what-do-they-do-for-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table or the same table. In simpler words, the foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary key or a unique key in the first table.

[image]

This takes us to Primary key. The customers table contains a unique key on each row called customerNumber this is the primary key for the table. On the orders table we have the orderNumber column which is the primary key for that table.

The orders table has a foreign key link back to the customers table though the customer Number.  We call the customer Number the foreign key.

Customer Table:

```
customerNumber CustomerName.
       1           Bob
       2           Jane
```

Order table:

```
OrderNumber customerNumber   Status
       1           1         Shipped
       2           1         Exploded
```

Using the data above if you wanted to see what orders bob had you would take the primary key being bobs customer id and check the order table for all rows containing the it.  This is the foreign key linking two tables.

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key is another table's primary key. It is used to link the two tables.
Example: we have 2 tables (Person & Employee)

Person has primary key: personID,
Employee has primary key: employeeID

An employee is a person so they have to be linked.

Employee has foreign key: personID

So, for every Employee there is a Person linked to it (where the personID in Employee is the same as the personID in Person).

Answer (score 1):

A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.

A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.

The table containing the foreign key is called the child table, and the table containing the candidate key is called the referenced or parent table.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

You use it to link two table together and it makes your data integrity better. You should always use foreign keys to link table references, unless you have clear reason not to.

Let's say you have `Foobar` table with `UserId` column and `User` table with `Id` column. You use foreign key to link `UserId` column from `Foobar` table to `User` table's `Id` column.

After that if you have `Foobar` row with `UserId` of 1 and try to delete row from `User` that has `Id` column value of 1 you get an error because `Foobar` references it. Also inserts are validated, let's say you try to insert row to `Foobar` table with `UserId` that doesn't exists in `User` table and you'll get an error as well.